# Rules erases the last value inserted

Tags: rules

i've an import module built with Rules which imports my users. An user can have one or many conventions. I manage these conventions with taxonomy. Conventions are store in my user fields, 'Number of values' under Field settings as 'Unlimited'
My point is, i cannot add many conventions to an user, only the last convention keep in store.
This is how i did:

```
{ "rules_updatepartenaireslistbatch" : {
    "LABEL" : "UpdatePartenairesListBatch",
    "PLUGIN" : "action set",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "wsclient", "rules_conditional" ],
    "ACTION SET" : [
      { "data_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "wsclient_ws_applicam_partenaire_FiltresPartenaire",
            "param_codePartenaire" : [ "" ],
            "param_complet" : 0,
            "param_conventions" : [ "" ],
            "param_raisonSociale" : [ "" ],
            "param_statutCode" : [ "" ],
            "param_typesAttribut" : [ "" ],
            "param_ville" : [ "" ],
            "param_top" : "20"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "data_created" : { "data_filtrepartenaire" : "Created data" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "wsclient_ws_applicam_partenaire_GetListePartenaires",
            "param_numSite" : "1058",
            "param_filtres" : [ "data-filtrepartenaire" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "data_created" : { "data_getlistpartenaire" : "Created data" } }
        }
      },
      { "wsclient_ws_applicam_partenaire_GetListePartenaires" : {
          "USING" : { "param_parameters" : [ "data-getlistpartenaire" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "result" : { "result_list_partenaire" : "GetListePartenairesResponse" } }
        }
      },
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "result-list-partenaire:GetListePartenairesResult" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "partenaire_item" : "Current list item" },
          "DO" : [
            { "data_convert" : {
                "USING" : { "type" : "text", "value" : [ "partenaire-item:id" ] },
                "PROVIDE" : { "conversion_result" : { "string_id" : "Conversion result" } }
              }
            },
            { "entity_query" : {
                "USING" : {
                  "type" : "user",
                  "property" : "name",
                  "value" : "PART_[string-id:value]",
                  "limit" : "1"
                },
                "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "part_fetched" : "Fetched entity" } }
              }
            },
            { "CONDITIONAL" : [
                {
                  "IF" : { "data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "part-fetched:0" ] } },
                  "DO" : [
                    { "entity_create" : {
                        "USING" : {
                          "type" : "user",
                          "param_name" : "PART_[string-id:value]",
                          "param_mail" : "PART_[string-id:value]@here.invalid"
                        },
                        "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_part" : "Created entity" } }
                      }
                    },
                    { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "entity-part" ], "immediate" : 1 } },
                    { "user_add_role" : { "account" : [ "entity-part" ], "roles" : { "value" : { "5" : "5" } } } },
                    { "user_unblock" : { "account" : [ "entity-part" ] } }
                  ]
                },
                { "ELSE" : [
                    { "variable_add" : {
                        "USING" : { "type" : "user", "value" : [ "part-fetched:0" ] },
                        "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "entity_part" : "Added variable" } }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            { "LOOP" : {
                "USING" : { "list" : [ "partenaire-item:conventions" ] },
                "ITEM" : { "convention" : "Current list item" },
                "DO" : [
                  { "entity_query" : {
                      "USING" : {
                        "type" : "taxonomy_term",
                        "property" : "name",
                        "value" : [ "convention:libelle" ],
                        "limit" : "1"
                      },
                      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched" : "Fetched entity" } }
                    }
                  },
                  { "CONDITIONAL" : [
                      {
                        "IF" : { "data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "entity-fetched" ] } },
                        "DO" : [
                          { "entity_create" : {
                              "USING" : {
                                "type" : "taxonomy_term",
                                "param_name" : [ "convention:libelle" ],
                                "param_vocabulary" : "conventions"
                              },
                              "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
                            }
                          },
                          { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "entity-created" ], "immediate" : 1 } }
                        ]
                      },
                      { "ELSE" : [
                          { "variable_add" : {
                              "USING" : { "type" : "taxonomy_term", "value" : [ "entity-fetched:0" ] },
                              "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "entity_created" : "Added variable" } }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  { "data_set" : {
                      "data" : [ "entity-part:field-conventions:0" ],
                      "value" : [ "entity-created" ]
                    }
                  },
                  { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "entity-part" ], "immediate" : 1 } },
                  { "drupal_message" : { "message" : [ "entity-created:name" ] } }
                ]
              }
            },
            { "component_rules_update_partenaire" : { "user" : [ "entity-part" ], "partenaire" : [ "partenaire-item" ] } }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The aim is simple.
- I get all users from a webservice
- I do a loop on users
    - I loop on user conventions
        - if convention doesn't exist as taxonomy term, i create it
        - else, I had the taxonomy term in a variable
        - I use a "set_data" to add the convention to the user

Ex: one of my user has "SPORT" and "CINEMA" in conventions. Only "CINEMA" is stored.

Comment: What's a "boucle"? In English that's a _yarn with a looped or curled ply, or fabric woven from this yarn._ Perhaps not what you meant :)

Comment: please apologize, i've fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the Taxonomy user field (Convention) allows multiple values.

1. Go to Admin > Configuration > People > Account Settings > Manage Fields
2. Edit the Term Reference field (in your case, Convention)
3. Set 'Number of values' under Field settings as 'Unlimited' or 2 or as desired
4. Save
5. Execute the rule and check

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Supriya Rajgopal

Comment: Thank for your reponse but unfortunately, i've already applied this configuration :(

Comment: @billyJoe add this info to your question, or emphase it more if it's already there, please. I couldn't see it, and Supriya's answer is most obvious thing to tell when somebody does not know you already checked it.

Comment: i've added this information to my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved !
I had simply to replace the data set by "Add an item to a list". So i had each convention in my loop in the user's convention list.